# How to convert surf to 3D object using matlab

Tags: matlab, surf

I have 3 vectors with size `x = 500`, `y = 500` but `z = 500*500`. Here `z` is height from `-3` to `3`. I have displayed this using `surf(x,y,z)`, but my problem is here I want to convert it as 3D object which is having same size `x=500`, `y=500`, `z=500`. Experts, how can I convert this?

Answer (score 1):

From `help surf`:

> SURF(x,y,Z) and SURF(x,y,Z,C), with two vector arguments replacing
>       the first two matrix arguments, must have length(x) = n and
>       length(y) = m where [m,n] = size(Z).  In this case, the vertices
>       of the surface patches are the triples (x(j), y(i), Z(i,j)).
>       Note that x corresponds to the columns of Z and y corresponds to
>       the rows.

Therefore:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);      %// replicate vectors appropriately
xyz   = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];   %// make [X,Y,Z] triplets
```

---

**EDIT**: See image below.

[image]

In this image, there are 3 distinct `x`-coordinates, 3 distinct `y`-coordinates, but **9** distinct `z`-coordinates. The 3D object will therefore contain **9** points, generally represented by **9**×3 coordinates.

I understand you want to either reduce this somehow to **3**×3 coordinates, or represent it somehow as **3×3×3**=27 coordinates....I just don't get *how* you want to do that.

So, please, provide a clear and simple picture of what you want, and I'll be able to help you much better :)

Comment: I have tried this but I have been getting size of xyz is  [250000 1]... Actually i need [500 500 500]. How do i get ?

Comment: I have skipped last step and x size 500*500 and y size is 500*500 and z size is 500*500  but i need x=500,y=500 and z=500 so that i can get a 3D object which has size [500 500 500].

Comment: @Dams: Originally, you have 500×500 XYZ triplets, which you generate with the `meshgrid` step. You seem to want to reduce that somehow to only 500 triplets. It's just not possible to represent your original 3D object with only 500 points without losing most of the information. Meaning: what you say you want will only be a slice of your 3D object, 1/500th of the original width.

Comment: Originally, I have surface which is taken from surf function. surf(x,y,z) here z is height from -3 to 3. is possible to convert this height in terms of 500 slices. if possible we will get 3d object which will be having size 500*500*500.

Comment: @Dams: I think I'm not understanding you correctly. It's true that there will be 500×500×500 points (so 3·500³ numbers to represent them). But you say you want 3 arrays of length 500 each. That's only 3·500 numbers, and not enough to represent your object, unless all of the 500 layers are exactly the same. So, please clarify.

Comment: Whenever we use surf function it gives 3D plot with height as z coordinate. In my example 3D plot is showing as x=0 to 500, y=0 to 500 and z=-3 to 3. So i want to create 3D object from this 3D plot which is given by surf function. if i create it i will be having 3 dimension image. i.e 500*500*S no need of z should be 500. it can be number of slices.  http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38945-fractional-brownian-field-or-surface-generator

Comment: I do agree for your edit. Convert it as solid object and cut it as slices. then each slice has z height x width and y length. That is the problem which i am facing how can i convert it as solid object and cut it. :)

Comment: @Dams: The 500×500 matrix you have for `z` is formatted like this: `z(1,:) ⇒ [x(1,1) y(1,:)], z(2,:) ⇒ [x(2,1) y(2,:)], ...`, etc. So, to get the first slice: `slice = [repmat(x(1,1),size(y,1),1), y(1,:).' z(1,:).']`. To get the `n`th slice: `slice = @(n) [repmat(x(n,1),size(y,1),1), y(n,:)' z(n,:)']` (I haven't tested this; perhaps it's the transpose of what I say).

Comment: tz=  [0.0180   -0.1432    0.0994    0.3691    0.2627
    0.0155    0.0268    0.0499    0.2093    0.4217
   -0.0900    0.2040   -0.0837    0.1080    0.0566
    0.3319    0.4197    0.2184    0.2670    0.2202
    0.7514    1.0128    1.0907    0.4802    0.3293] , tx=[0.3000    0.6000    0.9000    1.2000    1.5000 ] ty=[0.3000    0.6000    0.9000    1.2000    1.5000]. i have tested but getting an error CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent... Can you test it and elaborate more.

Comment: @Dams: `reshape(tz,[],numel(tx))` and repeat.